# Questions about involute and evolute.

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a couple of questions regarding differential geometry.

1. Can two different curves have the same involute curve? It seems possible to me, but I can't be sure.
2. In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xgtMQ7WSzQ) lecture, at around 12:00, the lecturer says let $P$ and $Q$ be two points on any curve, Draw normals at both points. As $Q$ approaches $P$, the point of intersection of the two normals will eventually stabilize. He goes on to say the limit of the point of intersection is the osculating centre at $P$.

I don't understand this. If $Q$ is at $P$, then the two normals will be co-incident. Hence, when $Q$ is *almost* at $P$, shouldn't the two lines *almost* be parallel, and hence the limit of the point of intersection at infinity?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$1.$ If two curves $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ have the same involute curve $\iota$ then (apart from exceptional points) both $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ can be obtained from $\iota$ by constructing the evolute (locus of centers of curvature) of $\iota$; so they have to coincide.

$2.$ It is true that the two normals will be coincident at the end of the limiting process. But if the curvature of the given curve is nonzero at the point in question, the point of intersection of the two normals *will not go off to* $\infty$, but will have a limiting position on the normal held fixed. You can convince yourself of this by considering a curve $y=f(x)$ with $f(0)=f'(0)=0$, $\>f''(0)>0$ and letting a point $Q:=\bigl(t,f(t)\bigr)$ tend to $P:=(0,0)$. Do the computations!

Answer (score 0):

I am avoiding equations and symbols.

1. The involute of a base curve starts at a given cusp point ***on the base curve***. That means the cusp point and base curve cannot be taken apart. So different curves *cannot share a common involute*. The curves have to be the same.

( Btw however if starting point is chosen differently ( when unwinding a taut string on the base curve)  then another involute comes about. There are infinitely many involutes on any given curve).

2. The concept of a derivative or finite limit in differential calculus is that the differentials on the numerator and denominator should *both* tend to zero.

When inclination of a line with respect to another goes to zero there are no such *two small differentials* when parallelism occurs during rolling contact at 12 min 0 sec in his lecture.